# Unable to run tests in Microsoft Test Manager data and diagnostics error

Tags: microsoft-test-manager

I am trying to run a manual test case in Microsoft Test Manager (2013) using a test lab.  When I run the test it shows the following error:

*Data and diagnostics cannot be collected
An error occurred while initializing diagnostic data adapters. Abort your session and start again.
Timed out while initializing data and diagnostics adapters.
If the Windows Firewall does not have Microsoft Test Manager added to the exceptions list and set to be enabled, the initialization for the data and diagnostics adapters can time out. Verify that the exceptions list for the Windows Firewall includes Microsoft Test Manager (mtm.exe). For more information about this, see:
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=83134
For more information about issues that can cause initialization of data and diagnostics adapters to time out, see:
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=254562.*

I have been searching for an answer and trying various things now for a couple of days and can't resolve the issue.  Helpfully of the 2 links it gives you in the error the first did not help and the second didn't link to a working page. People who have posted a similar error in forums have resolved their issues by correcting the firewall however the firewall on my local PC and the firewall on the virtual machine are both off.

This is what I have checked:

- Firewalls are all off
- My test agent is set up on the virtual machine and shows under my test controllers correctly
- The lab has a ready status and I can see the agent is online.
- My test settings are currently set up to collect no data (in the hope that would help but it has not).
- The test environment for running the tests is set to the correct environment.
- I have tried extending the time out period in the mtm.exe.config and the QTAgent configs on the remote machine for when I kick off the test runner.
- I have checked the firewall logs on the virtual machine when test runner fails and there appears to be no issues there.

As you can probably tell I have been trying to fix this for a while!

Has anyone seen this error before and been able to resolve it?  Any guidance on some things to try that I haven't already listed would be really appreciated.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this issue, for a manual test the test agent needs to be installed on the local machine as well as on the virtual machine for the automation tests.  This was the step I had missed.  Once the test agent was installed on my local machine this error disappeared.  It is a misleading error message but if you have this problem, make sure the test agent is on all of the machines in the environment and configured correctly.  Part of the issue here was my misunderstanding as I thought I could use the VM for my manual tests too which is not the case.